# jstat and ksysguard

Tags: java, linux

Is there any way that I can get the output of jstat (in particular the -gcutil output) into ksysguard so that I can keep track of how a collection of java processes are doing from a garbage collection perspective?

I know that jconsole has similar visualisations but I would prefer it if I could get the data into ksysguard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box because KSysGuard requires output in a particular format. However, it would not be too difficult to write a program that adapts jstat output to the format required by KSysGuard. There is a [tutorial](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Sensors) available on KDE TechBase. You'll be creating what's called a *custom sensor*.

Comment: I don't recommend trying that tutorial with any recent version of ksysguard - it is an undocumented and very buggy feature.